# Is it possible to cache iOS maps for use when the phone is offline?

Tags: ios, maps

Is it possible to request that an iOS app stores map images of a location so that they are available when the user is not connected to the internet?

i.e. if a user is in London, is it possible to force the app to source map images for Barcelona and keep them cached, so that once the user arrives in the location (without internet connectivity) the maps are already cached?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately apple doesn't allow anybody to do that.The `MapKit.framework` is strictly for displaying them. However use CoreGraphics to take a "screenshot" of the certain area(i.e. the map) and save it as an image, then display that image later.

Comment: Screenshotting an image of the map won't be good enough.  I need to make use of actual MapKit functionality.  Thanks for the answer - I'll mark it correct if nobody else contradicts you.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do that with the native Maps app (Google Maps on iOS 5/ "Apple Maps" on iOS 6) that comes with iOS, since simply Apple restricts the usage of the MapKit.framework. However, you might want to try out other map solution, such as Bing Maps or OpenStreetMap. These alternatives also provide useful map data that you can consider using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want online/offline maps you should use something like [Route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me).

It basically borrows the MapKit feature-set and API and provides a much broader range of options for mapping datasources.

Also, some notable branches have derived from that project, namely https://github.com/Alpstein/route-me, which provide even more features and better performance.